# How to take advantage of AWS Ec2 if my code cannot be parallelized (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I launched an EC2 instance to run my Matlab code faster. Despite the fact that I chose a machine much more powerful than my Mac, the code ran slower on AWS.

I asked to the Matlab support and they told me that the problem is that my code is not parallelized. Apparently, while using my Mac Matlab will automatically parallelize certain operations, but it does not on AWS (this is what I understood, does it make sense? Why should that be the case?).

I parallelized my code to find out that the parallelized version runs slower on my Mac. After some research I came to the conclusion that there might be two reasons for that:

1. When I parallelize (e.g., use a `parfor`) each worker operates with one core and this shuts down the "automatic parallelization" of Matlab
2. the part that takes the most time in my code is a loop in which each operation takes little time, but the loop is long (many of these iterations). As each operation does not take a lot of time, the overhead time outweighs the "benefits".

My question is: how can I take advantage of EC2 if parallelizing my code does not solve the problem?

Why is multi-threading off on EC2? Can I activate it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your specific question about managing threading on each worker in your pool:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/discover-clusters-and-use-cluster-profiles.html

"Number of computational threads to use on each worker" is the cluster setting you would want to change. Its default is 1, which is a reasonable default when choosing as many workers as your have cores available, but you are free to change it, and doing so will enable MATLAB functions that are internally threaded to make use of multiple threads.